# Double tap to wake on Amazon Fire tablet

Tags: screen, touch

In most Samsung Galaxy phones, it is possible to wake the phone by tapping the screen twice which is a very convenient feature.

I tried the same thing on the Amazon Fire HD tablet (2021 edition) and found that it is not working on my Fire device.

Is there a way to do this, whether by changing the setting or installing an app?

Comment: which OS does the device use? ... BTW, I have had several Samsung phones, and none of them responded to a double tap

Comment: Amazon Fire tablets run an entirely different operating system compared to a Samsung Galaxy phone.  It sounds like your tablet doesn't support the feature you want to use.

Comment: @jsotola depending on the Android version, it's on Settings - Advanced features - Motions and gestures - Double tap to turn on screen.

Comment: As far as I know the kernel has to be made to support this feature. Some OEMs (and many Custom ROMs) support this, while the rest don't. If you don't find the relevant setting in your Settings app than your system doesn't support it.